# How to disable (or, remove) "From email" linking and versions associated with a macOS Apple Mail "Save Attachment…" PDF?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, pdf, preview

How to disable (or remove) "From email" linking and versions associated with a macOS Mail "Save Attachment…" PDF via a setting? or by some scripting/automation approach?

The action was to "Save Attachment…" of a PDF a recieved email. No edits were done by me to the PDF file or to the revieved email. So, the version and link back to the email was created in the "Save Attachment…" process.

Ideally, I would like to disable this whatever-it-is email linking feature.

Alternately, I would like to know some process which can remove this linking in a scriptable or automated way.

Note: A work-around is to `Print…` and `Save as PDF…` each file manually to another new PDF.

[image]

[image]

[image]